# filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient CSS property not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using pieces of twitter's `bootstrap` css for our nav bar. Naturally everything looks great in Chrome and Firefox, but total crap in IE. I'm stumped because they have the proper css filter command for the gradient in IE, and, after doing some research, I found that occasionally IE will have a problem in the color codes are not 3 digits Hex, so I changed everything over and still have the same issue.

Here is how the gradient looks in

Chrome

[image]

and IE

[image]

and here is the CSS

```
.navbar-inner {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: #36C;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,       #33C, #69C);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,    #33C, #69C);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from( #33C), to(#69C));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,    #33C, #69C);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,     #33C, #69C);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top,    #33C, #69C);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='    #33C', endColorstr='#69C', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn-navbar {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #36C;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,   #33C, #66C);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,    #33C, #66C);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from( #33C), to(#66C));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,    #33C, #66C);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,     #33C, #66C);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top,    #33C, #66C);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='    #33C', endColorstr='#66C', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #66C #66C #000000;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the gradient filter required full `#AARRGGBB` colour codes. Just `#33C` won't do. Try `#003333CC` instead. If that comes out transparent, try `#7F3333CC` - I can never remember which way around it goes.

PS. Try IE10. But get rid of the `-ms-linear-gradient` since it never existed since they went straight to `linear-gradient`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change the gradient in IE (still the same display and in that screen shot). However, it did make the gradient go away in Chrome, so it was just one solid color.

Comment: Hmm... Well, personally I don't think it's worth worrying about - just drop the filter altogether and use a solid colour for old IE users. Also, you should change your `linear-gradient` rules to `linear-gradient(to bottom, #33C, #69C)`

Comment: `filter` is becoming an actual property, just with values that actually make sense rather than DXImageTransform nonsense. So this is probably why your gradient disappeared there.